# How can I use Razor in non-web applications... such as a mail merge program?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Has anyone attempted to use Razor outside of a Web Application, such as within a C# commandline application?

Generally how would one go about using Razor to do a simple mail merge? It seems to be possible based on the comments of [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) blog post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this question: [Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

[Turn your Razor helpers into reusable libraries - Angle Bracket Percent - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidebb/turn-your-razor-helpers-into-reusable-libraries)

and

[davidebbo / RazorSingleFileGenerator / overview – Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/razorsinglefilegenerator/overview)