# ASP.NET MVC - Rendering and sending output thought webservice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, render, razor

Does anyone knows the way to parse .cshtml layout file and render output as string in webservice? Any tips ?

In ASP.NET C# something like this
                XhtmlTextWriter xhtmltextwriter = new XhtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);

```
            // Create a new Page and add the control to it.
            using (Page page = new Page())
            {
                foreach (Control item in controls)
                {
                    page.Controls.Add(item);
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, xhtmltextwriter, false);
            }
```

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Check the answers for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can check newest Phil Haack's blog post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx). He explains how to use Razor engine to parse *.cshtml files. From this you can use it everywhere, fe. send it through web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely host the Razor engine in a Web Service. I wrote a blog post about it here: http://anur.se/razorhost. If you want something simpler, I'd suggest using [Razor Engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/), which abstracts away the complex stuff and provides simple facades like `Razor.Parse(template, model)`.