# How to include HTML document in .NET application with variable fields?

Tags: c#, .net, html, embedded-resource

I have a C#/.NET app which currently uses StringBuilder to generate an HTML email message.

A new message format has been developed and now includes more formatting and CSS. I'd like to avoid appending each line of the file using StringBuilder, so I thought it best to include the HTML file as a resource.

However, there are about 21 variables within the CSS and HTML which I need to change on the fly. My first thought was to replace them with the standard String.Format placeholders ({0}, {1} etc) but when viewing the HTML, validation complains about these.

I'm rather stumped as to what the best practice is for storing a 200-line HTML file and changing parts of it before inclusion in an email.

Example:

Within the CSS, I need to change the color of certain elements, like this:

```
#header
{
    background-color: {0};
}
```

And within the HTML, I need to change strings and URLs, like this:

```
<img src="{1}" />
<span>{2}</span>
```

It seems including the HTML as a resource in the project would be best, but trying to use String.Format with that resource, regardless if it would work, is a poor method because of the aforementioned validation errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is it a problem that validation fails on the "template HTML" before the placeholders are replaced ? IMHO the only important point is the it validates correctly AFTER replacing the placeholders with some content!

Comment: Then you'd have to remember which means what. And you need maintain argument count consistent. Use replaceable tokens like <%token_name%> and create simple find-replace method to replace tokens from some dictionary.

Comment: This question is like a rose in a Stack Overflow full of weeds. I hope it gets an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using {1} use a name e.g. Table1HeaderImage, then instead of using String.Format use String.Replace.
You could have a collection of thingies to put in thehtml then, a quick loop, even extra attributes for customisation from users version, etc.

Comment: My middle name, well part of it. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try [t4 tamplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx)

With t4 template you can even do more complex things like

```
<table>
<# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
   { #>
     <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
         <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> </tr>
 <# } #>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Razor engine to render a HTML string:

```
<h2>Items:</h2>
@foreach(var item in list)
{
    <p>Item: @item.Description</p>
}
```

These answers [Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net) give some nice links to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a preprocessed T4 text template file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259
One of the nice features T4 text templates is that they can be used to auto generate any kind of text file.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is something like this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Email/email.html"));
string email_html = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

email_html = email_html.Replace("[link]", activation_link);
```

Comment: This is essentially what I went with; thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `<%0%>`, `<%1%>`, etc. instead of `{0}`, `{1}`, etc.

At runtime, you would:

1. Replace all `{` with `{{` and `}` with `}}`
2. Replace all `<%` with `{` and `%>` with `}`
3. `String.Format()`

You could also do as Val Bakhtin suggested, and use names instead of numbers. Then the process would be simply:

1. Replace all `<%name%>` with `dictionary["name"]`