# Can I use Razor Script in a C# console application (instead of using it in MVC3 application)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net)

I want to use Razor script in a console application.

The application I am creating is rich client (non web) application and I don't want to use MVc3 web hoster for it.

Can I use Razor script in a C# console application?

Comment: Huh? What? Razor is for markup, how would this even begin to work in a console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Answer is here
[Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net)

Razor is widely used as Email renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference to System.Web.Razor.dll, and call the classes defined in that System.Web.Razor.dll