# C# MVC 5 Converting html view to PDF to send an email attachment in Bussness Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I want to email a PDF sales report to all the agents and this PDF need to be generated dynamically for each agent. I used `ItextSharp` for that but that requires too much fiddling with html code. Finally I landed on `Rotativa`, it works well but there are almost more then few thousands of agents and I have a separate Business Layer to do this job. How do I make Rotativa to work in business layer?

```
 var pdfResult = new ViewAsPdf("CreateIMDStatmentReport", _IReportManagement.GetIMDStatmentReportByIMDCode(imdCode));
 var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);     
 System.Net.Mail.Attachment data = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(binary), MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
```

1. How to get a view in separate Business Layer?
2. How do I deal with ControllerContext?

Note: In future this view will be stored in database and will be rendered as VirtualPath

Comment: Ty! @ManfredRadlwimmer for editing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

> For the `view` I used the absolute paths. 
>   And for the `ControllerContext` ,I passed its object as a parameter from controller.
>   Also I used `System.Web.Mvc` package

Thank you to all!

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need Razor rendering outside ASP.NET MVC project, take a look at this discussion on this topic (link below). You will still need to figure out if this works with Rotavia, but I would start from this.

[Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net)

From the discussion, following framework is addressing you scenarion, but again I can not confirm that it will work with Rotavia, perhaps you can use another HTML-to-PDF converter component.

*"The framework helps you when you want to use Razor to render reports, e-mails, source code, HTML, or whatever, **outside the MVC environment**"*

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/423141/Razor-2-0-template-engine-supporting-layouts

Comment: Ok, I see you solved it. Anyway I will leave an answer just as another option for people to discuss.

Comment: Thank you! for the reply @EDP.