# Place holder for unspecifed number of variable in html/C#

Tags: c#, html

I'm making a HTML mail template. How would someone go around making a placeholder in html? i have an array of strings i want to parse in, in a certain column. But as expected from my code it only replaces the text "row1" once, so i only get the first string item. 
so how do i make a string[] placeholder in html that will just add a new line for each string in the array? So what to replace "Row1" with?

The html code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="leftColumnContent">
                    <p>Row1</p>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

The C# mail code ive tried:

```
        StreamReader myreaderhtml = new StreamReader("htmlemail.html");
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("VUCresult.txt");
        string htmlmailbody = myreaderhtml.ReadToEnd();



        foreach (string s in lines)
        {

            htmlmailbody = htmlmailbody.Replace("Row2", namingConversion.GetADUserDisplayName(s));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            htmlmailbody = htmlmailbody.Replace("Row1", lines[i]);
        }
```

Comment: I have, and i did. Nothing that worked for me. so just looking for a way to display entire array line by line.

Comment: use HTML attributes in EditorFor:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel that's called a text templating engine. Plenty of solutions exist already for this problem, and implementing it yourself is quite a bit of work. You could take a look at Razor, see [Is it possible to use Razor View Engine outside asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628895/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-view-engine-outside-asp-net).

Anyhow, to support looping, you'll need to make up some kind of indicator in your template saying "repeat this for every row".

You could do that something like this:

```
$repeat(myTableRow)
<tr>
    <td class="leftColumnContent">
        <p>$value1</p>
    </td>
    <td class="leftColumnContent">
        <p>$value2</p>
    </td>
</tr>
$endrepeat(myTableRow)
```

Then in your code, you'll have to find this block by name ("myTableRow"), and save the inner text (`<tr>...</tr>`).

Then you can replace the placeholders (`$value1`, `$value2`) in that inner text for every row, and output it.