# Conditional compilation does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, conditional-compilation

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951128/c-and-asp-net-mvc-using-if-directive-in-a-view) here on stackoverflow want to load a different css when compiling for release mode.

**Code:**

```
@{ #if (Debug) 
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
#else
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site-min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
#endif 
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
@{ #if (Debug) }
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{ #else }
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site-min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{ #endif  }
```

I tried to DEBUG in uppercase
But no change has no effect when compiling Debug to Release

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug/4697570#4697570

How about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951128/c-and-asp-net-mvc-using-if-directive-in-a-view/2951200#2951200), if you want this sort of thing to work, you can use a property in your Model to drive the View's conditional stuff, so the C# sets the Model's boolean (`IsDebug`, or whatever) via the compile time directive stuff and the View relies on that.

So your Model would end doing something like:

```
bool IsDebug = true;

#if (!DEBUG)
IsDebug = false;
#endif
```

and your View would do something like:

```
@if(Model.IsDebug) 
{ 
}
else
{
}
```

You could also use ViewBag/ViewData to hold that boolean value too, I suppose.

---

UPDATE:

Base on your comments, here's something you *could* do:

Create a new `BaseController` class which inherits from `Controller`.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
   ...
   protected BaseController()
   {
      bool indebug = false;

      #if DEBUG
      indebug = true;
      #endif

      ViewBag.InDebug = indebug;
   }
}
```

and have your Controllers inherit from this rather than Controller.

Then in your _Layout.cshtml you *could* do this:

```
@if (ViewBag.InDebug)
{
}
else
{
}
```

This seems to work OK.

Comment: The problem is that this code should be executed for all pages.
What is a CSS file for all pages.
Once a controller has only one may ask, would have to put in all the controllers and that I did not want.
The code is in _Layout.cshtml (master layout)
Why can not I use the Direct View?

Comment: see my additional info in my answer - perhaps it will work for you too.