# Public Conditional Razor Views with minified JS and CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 to develop my website. I'm using Grunt to minify my CSS and JS. Everything works fine, but I need to change the route source of my files if I'm making a publish (release mode) or I'm debugging (I need to read my CSS and JS clearly).

Something like this:

> [Debug Mode]

```
<script src="scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

> [Relase Mode or Public Mode]

```
<script src="dist/myscript.min.js"></script>
```

I have read this post on StackOverflow([Razor view engine, how to enter preprocessor(#if debug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug)) and I don't like the proposed solution **because I think** (not sure) that the loaded Razon View is going to check always in Production Server if it's in release or debug mode and I think that it's not necessary.

Can someone confirm if I am right? Will I will need make the changes manually? Any other solution?

Thanks!! Regards!!

Comment: Consider writing a static helper function that returns the script URL path, which reads from the web.config file (and is appropriately transformed by the build configuration)

Comment: But I work with a a lot of files... about 20 JS and more than 10 css in debug mode...

Comment: You might only need the helper return a string partial URL, so 'scripts/' in debug and 'dist/' in release.  May not help in your specific situation, but I've seen similar things work.

Comment: Thanks @IanL but it's not going to work for me ;) I have different folders...

Comment: Any reason why you don't use Bundles and have MVC do all this out of the box?

Comment: Because I minify the files with Grunt... Can you show me how bundles can help me? Thanks

Comment: And I'm using bower for take the JS and CSS too :)

Comment: Best you read the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). When using bundles, the non-minified versions will be used in debug mode. In release mode, if no corresponding -min- file exist, the files will be minified. If a -min- file does exist, it will be used.

Comment: Can I concat files with bundles? Thank you so much!!

Comment: What do you mean by _concat files_? A bundle can include multiple files, for example `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myScripts").Include("~/Scripts/myFirstScript.js", "~/Scripts/mySecondScript.js"));` In the view you use `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myScripts")` In debug mode those 2 files will be rendered. In release mode, they will be minified by the framework, but if the `Scripts` folder also includes `myFirstScript-min.js` and `mySecondScript-min.js`, then those minified files will used instead.

Comment: Ok, these files will be rendered.., but i will have one or two files? I need to have just one minified file to best performance request... (Last question ;))

Comment: If you mean you have 2 or more un-minified files and then you create 1 single minified file, then no, it wont work. But I suspect you wont get any better performance by doing that anyway. One of the many features of bundling is that all the files defined in a Bundle are combined into one file (in release mode) as explained in the documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could accomplish this is to just check for debug mode in the http context.

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <script src="scripts/myscript.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="dist/myscript.min.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: @diegosasw you should be using the `environment` tag helpers for asp.net core projects

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Thanks to [Shoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950321/shoe) I learned about the existence of environment tag helpers, so instead of my old answer where I achieved the same manually, we can now use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/sasw.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <!-- Google Analytics here for example -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**
A solution for Razor pages that should also work with Razor views (dotnet core 3.1+) could be to inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` and to render conditionally depending on the current environment (defined by the global variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`)
At your `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment Env
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    @if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/sasw.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    }
    else
    {
        <!-- Google Analytics here for example -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    }
</head>
```

This solution plays nicely with the [bundle and minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) policy defined at `bundleconfig.json`

In my case the `bundleconfig.json` looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/sasw.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/sasw.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

and I have added a nuget called `BuildBundlerMinifier` that minifies & bundles automatically the js and css placing the minified version in the same folder as the original one.

PS: Remember to ignore (e.g: at `.gitignore`) `*.min.js` and `*.min.css` if you follow the same approach, to let the build process generate a new one each time without committing it to source control.