# How can I use Preprocessor Directives to Conditionally Include Specific CSS Snippets?

Tags: css, msbuild, blazor, visual-studio-2022, preprocessor-directive

Problem:

- I have two build configurations. Each has its own preprocessor symbol: DEV and PROD.
- I would like each build to have its own background-image color.
- For C# files, I know that I can use preprocessor directives with the build symbols to conditionally generate code.

Question: How can I do this with a CSS file (like below)?

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
#if PROD
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff80ed 0%, gainsboro 90%);
#else
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
#endif
}
```

---

UPDATE:

- Alternatively, I'd be just as happy creating a `site.css.dev` and `site.css.prod` if that would solve the problem.

Comment: Three approaches: 1.) Choose a CSS Preprocessor and add it to your build steps. A starting point for learning about available tools may be ["Popular CSS preprocessors ..."](https://raygun.com/blog/css-preprocessors-examples/). You need a preprocessor that supports conditional logic and that supports passing your DEV|PROD flag. 2.) Maintain separate dev and prod files and have MSBuild copy the appropriate file, e.g. when the configuration is DEV, copy `site.css.dev` to `site.css`.  The build and/or packaging steps should use `site.css`.

Comment: 3.) If it is only the background color that is different between configurations, maintain a `site.css` file with say the PROD info. On a DEV build, modify the file before it is packaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2951200/109941):

1. Remove the `.sidebar` code from `MainLayout.razor.css`.
2. Add two new files in the `wwwroot\css` directory:

   1. `sidebar.Default.css`

```css
.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}
```

2. `sidebar.Prod.css`

```css
.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff80ed 0%, gainsboro 90%);
}
```

3. Modify `_Layout.cshtml` as follows:

```html
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        @{
            var isProd = false;
            #if PROD
            isProd = true;
            #endif
        }
        @if (isProd)
        {
            <link href="css/sidebar.Prod.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        }
        else
        {
            <link href="css/sidebar.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        }
        <link href="FooBar.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```