# Pre-processing equivalent for views in RAZOR/MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, compiler-directives

I'm looking for the equivalent of an

```
#if DEBUG
   //view elements to show just for debug builds
#if
```

for views in MVC3/Razor. What's the idiomatic method for implementing this type of a setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's too messy IMO. Views should be dumb, and focused on rendering HTML, not making build-based decisions.

Set properties in your view model if debug is configured, and render them out in the View.

If the properties are null (e.g non-debug), nothing will get rendered.

Comment: I'll just add that razor **can** handle preprocessor directives, but in this case it won't help because razor views are always compiled in debug mode, no matter what is set in web.config.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it checks debug value in the web.config file.

For instance:

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) {
    //view elements to show just for debug builds
}
```

The other option is use write your own HttpHelper extension

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDebug(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        #if DEBUG
          return true;
        #else
          return false;
        #endif
    } 
}
```

Then in your Razor code you can use it as:

```
@if (Html.IsDebug())
{ 
    //view elements to show just for debug builds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that in Razor as it doesn't compile the same way as C# code does.

So I'd say the best way to do it would be to do it in your controller and add it to a value in your model.

Edit: Here's some more info. The person here is suggesting an extension method that loads the appropriate code whether it's in debug or not: [asp.mvc view enteres #IF DEBUG in release configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378696/asp-mvc-view-enteres-if-debug-in-release-configuration)
Since you haven't told us what you'd like to do, i can't give you any 'code' answers.

Answer (score 0):

[**Preprocessor directives**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) (`#if`) are a language feature C#, which you can enter by using a [**razor code block**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#razor-code-blocks) (`@{}`) and then use a [**explicit delimited transition**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#explicit-delimited-transition) (`<text></text>`) or an [**explicit line transition**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#explicit-line-transition) (`@:`) to conditionally add html like this:

```cs
@{

#if DEBUG
{
    @:<div>Debug Mode</div>
}
#else
{
    <text>
        <div>
            Release Mode
        </div>
    </text>
}
#endif

}
```

**See Also**: [Preprocessor directives in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696175/1366033)